# Material snackbar appears in centre of screen before scrolling up from bottom

Tags: angular, angular-material2

New to Angular material and using the snackbar and dialog components

The issue I'm having is when opening the snackbar, it appears in the centre of the screen first, disappears and then slides up from the bottom.

Has anyone else come across this problem?

Below are my dependencies in my package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^5.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
    "@types/html2canvas": "0.5.32",
    "angular-maps": "^0.7.1",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.7.0",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.2",
    "bignumber.js": "^5.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "chalk": "^2.3.0",
    "contract-deployer": "^1.0.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "eth-lib": "^0.2.5",
    "ethjs-unit": "^0.1.6",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "express-validation": "^1.0.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "hbs": "~3.1.0",
    "helmet": "^3.9.0",
    "html2canvas": "^0.5.0-beta4",
    "ipfs-api": "^14.0.3",
    "joi": "^13.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jshint-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "json2csv": "^3.11.5",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "mongo-querystring": "^4.1.1",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.28",
    "mongoose": "^4.10.5",
    "ng2-nvd3": "^2.0.0",
    "nouislider": "^10.0.0",
    "oboe": "^2.1.4",
    "owl.carousel": "^2.2.0",
    "ramda": "^0.25.0",
    "randomhex": "^0.1.5",
    "request": "^2.83.0",
    "scrypt.js": "^0.2.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.4.3",
    "solc": "^0.4.11",
    "swarm-js": "^0.1.37",
    "validator": "^7.2.0",
    "websocket": "^1.0.25",
    "winston": "^2.4.0"
  }
```

Comment: What version of Material are you using? (Maybe add your package.json dependencies.) Do you get any errors on your console?

Comment: Hi and thanks, using Material2 "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
And getting no errors, I did notice that doing the same with dialogs as well

Comment: You're using an old version of Material. Maybe an `npm update` will help

Answer (score 1):

Answered

[Angular 5 Material snackbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48423110/angular-5-material-snackbar)